# Registry Path contains GUID and ® character

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I want to get the product version of the existing product in the Windows7 registry. Specifically, Value name: ProductVersion, and Value data: 10.2.1
The registry key names are:

```
(1) HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\InstallerCache\{B2DC393F-20A6-428A-8F33-45D1A93D0177}

(2) HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyCompany® Web Manager\8.1.0.21\UTIL
```

My questions are:
1. I am worried that the GUID are different on different machines. Can I just use it as is? 
2. I have problem to get the correct value from (2) in C# because of the ®. What should I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used copy/paste of the registry key to get it working. Using (char)174 still has problem.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this should be the right one

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx

```
char registered = (char)174;
```